# "have I ruined everything now or are you still going to come tomorrow?"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> So, have I ruined everything now or are you still going to come tomorrow?

Is "are you still going to come tomorrow?" closer in meaning to "are you still coming tomorrow?" or "are you still planning on coming tomorrow?"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future#:~:text=The%20going%2Dto%20future%20is%20one%20of%20several%20constructions%20used,see%20Future%20tense%20%C2%A7%20English).&text=The%20going%2Dto%20future%20is%20relatively%20informal%3B%20in%20more%20formal,%2Fare%20expected%20to%2C%20etc.

Comment: Did you look up "going to" in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Is "are you still going to come tomorrow?"  closest in meaning to

"are you **still coming tomorrow**?"

or

"are you **still planning on coming tomorrow?**"

I don't see any difference between the two. If you ask someone whether they are coming tomorrow, you are asking about their plans, not about a more-or-less certain future, like whether the sun will rise tomorrow.